# SSHFS mount remote directory which subfolder are mounted locally

Tags: replication, mount, failover, sshfs

- I have two servers FTPa and FTPb
- Each server is running PHP web file transfer app that sits in `/var/www/html/files/`
- On both servers some of the app subfolders are mounted with folders inside /sftp/ 
  E.g. `mount --bind /var/www/html/files/data/client1/ /sftp/client1/`

The purpose of the FTPb is to be the exact replica of FTPa (failover site, essentially). I used sshfs on FTPa to mount remote directory `/var/www/html/files/` of FTPb. As soon as I do that the local mounting between `/var/www/html/files/data/client1` and `/sftp/client1/` gets disabled.

Is there a way to keep `/var/www/html/files/data/client1` mounted to `/sftp/client1` and at the same time have `/var/www/html/files/` mounted to remote `/var/www/html/files` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work when you first mount the `/var/www/html/files` to remote directory and then use do the bind mount. However, I haven't tried such a scenario myself so it might not work.

Instead of using bind mounts here, I would change the application so that it uses `/sftp/client1` directly for that location. Without knowing further details of your application, I can't give precise instructions. However, I think that you need to adjust your webserver configuration and application code.

Then, I would use `lsyncd` to keep the contents of the servers in sync instead of `sshfs`.

Comment: thanks. how about making sftp users chroot straight into '/var/www/html/files/data/client1/'? Is that a good architechtural approach?

Comment: chroot jails are good if you want to restict access to single locations on your server. I think it would be useful in your use case.